# What is the default timeout of Monitor.TryEnter?

Tags: c#, multithreading

What is the default timeout of Monitor.TryEnter?

It isn't stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxbdx9xx(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(someObj))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask such a simple question, but my googling skill are turning down on me on this one.

Comment: Zero: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs,b35cea1f256fdaeb

Comment: Isn't -1 the value for infinity, it appear the be zero in the link.

Comment: "A value of –1 millisecond specifies an infinite wait." from MSDN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the different `TryEnter` overload documentation. Here is the the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw(v=vs.110).aspx) for the method in question.

> **Remarks**
>
> If successful, this method acquires an exclusive lock on the obj parameter. This method **returns immediately**, whether or not the lock is available.
> This method is similar to **Enter**, but it will **never block** the current thread. If the thread cannot enter without blocking, the method returns **false**, and the thread does not enter the critical section.

In other words, there is no timeout (timeout is zero).

Comment: Omg!, I got so own by msdn. This overload what actually replaced by "..." in my browser. :D, well it sure was really simple question :/